# JQuery Not Working Until Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

All the other answers I could find on the matter reference using .live which has since been replaced with .on

The script I'm trying to use does not work until I refresh the page. I understand that it's because the page itself doesn't refresh all the elements but rather injects them according to what has changed. I'm still a total noob so I'm probably butchering the concept but I'd like to figure out how to structure this so that it works whenever the page gets loaded rather than after refresh.

```
$('table tr')
.contents()
.filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 8;})
.replaceWith(function(){return this.data;})

console.log('Comment Remover Loaded')
```

I know I have to use .on but I'm quite unfamiliar with the syntax that Jquery uses and every method I've tried so far hasn't worked (probably because I haven't structured it correctly).

Thanks

Comment: did you place it inside `$(function () {});`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this method on page load by using jQuery load method as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table tr')
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 8;})
        .replaceWith(function(){return this.data;})

        console.log('Comment Remover Loaded')
    })
</script>
```

Comment: How would I execute this? I'm using this for a chrome extension- would I still be able to reference this as a .js file and have the manifest.json execute it?

Comment: The `$(function () {..}` block is called on ever page load and you do not need to call it. If the problem not solved please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... It still only works after I refresh it. The issue being that it needs to work after I navigate to a certain page- not after a refresh.